# Deleting "nan" from 2-d array in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a data set that is in a 2-d numpy array of size 25000 by 13.  There are numbers in 25 by 7 of that array and the rest is nan.  How do I remove all the nans?  I have tried:

```
test[~np.isnan(test)]
```

with "test" being my array and separately have tried (I believe they are the same)

```
test[np.logical_not(np.isnan(test))]
```

both of which put the 25 by 7 array into a 175 by 1 array after going through the operation.

Thank you in advance

Comment: What do you want to replace the `np.nan`'s with? Or is your desired result a 25x6 array?

Comment: Hello, you are new on stackoverflow take few minutes to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question to improve it. The current question is not properly exposed that why I assume it was downvoted

Comment: `test[boolean_mask]` produces a flat  result.  In general such a mask can remove differing numbers of items from each row or column, so it can't maintain a 2d layout.  By the way 25*6 is 150.  The (175,1) result puzzles me.

Comment: @user3483203 I would just like the 25x7 array left

Comment: I miss counted @hpaulj and it should be a 25x7 array which makes up the (175,1) array.  My mistake as I am still converting over from matlab to python

Comment: If you know that desired values are in a block, then the `reshape` as proposed is probably the easier solution.  An alternative is to mask whole rows and columns that contain only `nan`.  How were you doing this in MATLAB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track with your boolean mask, but the result must be one dimensional because the shape of a subset of a multidimensional array is ill-defined so it flattens it automatically. Luckily, it will flatten it in a predictable way. So, you just need to make it a 2d array again.

`test[~np.isnan(test)].reshape((25,7))` should achieve your desired result.

Comment: This worked great thank you! All appreciate the explanation as to why it was putting it all into a 1-d array.